# Repeatedly calling a function until the result falls within a tolerance

Tags: python-2.7

Write a function iterate with the following arguments:
f: a function
start: a numeric starting value
tol: a numerical tolerance (default value 1e-6)
itmax: a maximum number of iterations (default value 1000)

Starting from the initial value, your function should keep repeating calls to the function (e.g. y=f(y)) until the absolute value of f(y)-y is less than tol or the number of iterations is equal to itmax. For example, if start=1.01, f is math.sqrt, and tol=1e-4, the sequence would look like this:

On step 6, the absolute value of the difference is less than the tolerance (1e-4), so the function returns  [6, 1.0000777399813863].

Tests (should all be True):

```
def approx_equal(x,y,tol=1e-8):
    """helper function: test whether all elements of
       x and y are equal within tolerance
    """
    if len(x) != len(y):
       return(False)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if (abs(x[i]-y[i])>tol):
            return(False)
    return(True)

def disc_logist(x):
    """discrete logistic function"""
    return(1.5*x*(1-x))

print(approx_equal(iterate(disc_logist,0.5),[15, 0.33333433255312184]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(disc_logist,0.5,tol=1e-8),[22, 0.33333334113969143]))

def half(x):
    """just what it says"""
    return(x/2)

print(approx_equal(iterate(half,1000),[29, 9.313225746154785e-07]))
import math
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.sqrt,1.01,tol=1e-4),[6, 1.0000777399813863]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0),[34, 0.7390855263619245]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0,tol=1e-8),[46, 0.7390851366465718]))
print(approx_equal(iterate(math.cos,0,itmax=5),[5, 0.7013687736227565]))
```

This is what i have so far:

```
def iterate(f,start,tol=1e-6,itmax=1000):
    """function should keep repeating calls to the function until the absolute
     value of f(y)-y is less than tol or number of iterations is equal to itmax
     :f: a function
     :start: a numeric starting value
     :tol: a numerical tolerance
     :itmax: a maximum number of iterations"""
    import math
    y=start
    for i in range(itmax):
        y_2=f(y)
        if abs(y_2 - y) <tol:
            return y
        else:
            y=y_2
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Does it not work? Where does it fail?

Comment: `iterate` returns a number, which you pass to `approx_equal`, and try to call `len` on it. Numbers don't have lengths. What is `len(10)` for example?

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to return a list of values, instead of 1 value from `iterate`.

Comment: approx_equal is the test function ive been assigned. Im not sure how to change iterate in order to adapt for this probelm

Comment: Since the homework directions seem to be unclear, I'm guessing here: see how you just overwrite `y` every iteration? Change `y` to a list containing `start`, and `push`/`append` to it each loop instead of overwriting it. Then, check the last element of `y` when you compare it to `y_2`. You may need to clarify with your teacher though, as the instructions as posted are vague.

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying but im still very new to this. if i make y a string im not sure how to adjust for that with the rest of my code

Comment: You'll need to lookup how to use lists then; many tutorials are available. Posting such a tutorial here would be offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your immediate problem is to return not a single number, but a two element list containing first the number of iterations and second the answer - note that the instructions say (my emphasis):

> On step 6, the absolute value of the difference is less than the tolerance (1e-4), so the function returns **[6, 1.0000777399813863]**.

```
def iterate(f,start,tol=1e-6,itmax=1000):
    """function should keep repeating calls to the function until the absolute
     value of f(y)-y is less than tol or number of iterations is equal to itmax
     :f: a function
     :start: a numeric starting value
     :tol: a numerical tolerance
     :itmax: a maximum number of iterations"""
    import math
    y=start
    for i in range(itmax):
        y_2=f(y)
        if abs(y_2 - y) <tol:
            # Return the successful value - the last result, not the last input
            return [i, y_2]
        else:
            y=y_2
    # Return the next answer
    return [itmax, f(y)]
```

This will get `approx_equal()` working, but I haven't tested it completely to see if all the results match up.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you so much! It returned True for all examples except for the last one

Comment: Hmm, I haven't got the complete spec so I don't know why this is correct, but if for the final return I use `return [itmax, f(y)]` it works. I'll update my answer - now I think about it, this makes sense.

Comment: Please don't forget to [mark as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/222560) if this has helped you!